# Правильный способ обратиться к полю не выровненного объекта

Tags: c++, c, доступ, выравнивание

Не могу найти однозначного ответа на следующий вопрос.

Допустим, у меня имеется какая-то структура данных:

```
struct Data
{
    int id;
    double values[1024]
    // ...
    uint8_t flags;
    // ...
};
```

И она лежит в буфере в не выровненном состоянии. Мне известно смещение, по которому объект данной структуры лежит в буфере. Я бы хотел считать определенное поле из этого объекта. Например, поле `flags`.

```
uint8_t getFlags(uint8_t *_buffer, size_t _offset)
{
    uint8_t *pu = _buffer + _offset;
    // ...
}
```

1) Проблема в том, что `Стандарт C` говорит, что неопределенным поведением является даже попытка сохранить в указателе адрес с не правильным выравниванием:

```
Data *pd = (Data*)pu;// UB
```

2) Естественно, попытка разыменовать указатель, в котором хранится адрес с неподходящим для целевого типа выравниванием - это неопределенное поведение.

```
const uint8_t f = pd->flags;// UB
```

3) Я бы мог попытаться вытащить данные без разыменования:

```
uint8_t f;
memcpy(&f, pu + offsetof(Data, flags), sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Но этот способ выглядит подозрительно. Даже в рамках языка `C`.

В общем, я хочу понять, как правильно выковыривать определенные поля из объектов, которые лежат в буферах в не выровненном состоянии. Это частая задача, особенно при работе с сетью, драйверами и встраиваемыми системами.

Comment: В общем случае никак. В частном случае нужно поглядеть, как транслятор кладет структуру и ручками подобрать смещение для каждого поля. При этом надо помнить, что при смене ключей трансляции (например при смене уровня оптимизации) упаковка может измениться. А вообще для таких случаев надо пользоваться упакованными структурами.

Comment: Сугубо мое личное мнение, которое не более чем мнение :) - идеальных компиляторов нет, все вот такие тонкости - попытка снять ответственность за какие-то извращения оптимизаторов в будущем. А в реальных imperfect компиляторах - проверьте и работайте, не заморачиваясь. Укажите только - раз хотите работать с железом и т.п. - правильную упаковку (на байт надежнее всего) - и работайте. На то и `offsetof`, чтоб нормально работать :)

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо. Я пытаюсь писать правильный код, но в стандартах `C` и `C++` столько неоднозначностей, что вопросов становится больше, чем ответов...

Comment: дык, а (3) чем подозрительно выглядит? ЗЫ: кстати, возникновение самой задачи выглядит несколько странно — откуда появляется такой буфер, что соответствуют смещениям с паддингам и выравниваниями структуры, созданной компилятором? Такая необходимость иногда возникает, но вот это ИМХО как раз уже выглядит подозрительно и смахивает на ошибку...

Comment: Этот способ не выглядит подозрительно. В рамках языка C он всегда работает. А в С++ хранение в буферах объектов не standard layout является программной ошибкой, так что и там этот метод вполне работает. 2) такая попытка будет UB даже при правильном выравнивании.

Comment: Есть драйвер, который выплевывает в буфер кучу сложных объектов. Все эти объекты лежат в буфере в не выровненном состоянии. Есть обмен по последовательному порту, который так же складывает сложные объекты в буфер в не выровненном состоянии. Это лишь некоторые примеры того, зачем мне нужно считывать такие данные.

Comment: @MGNeo, соль в том, что если буфер получается от внешнего источника, то переносимости ради, в таких случаях структуру надо шпиговать аттрибутами `packed` и `alligned`, а это уже компиляторо-зависимые вещи (по крайней мере в Си) и ориентироваться на стандарт здесь бессмысленно, а от конкретного компилятора вполне можно ожидать достаточно определённого поведения... А если не заботиться о переносимости, то сегодня для многих архитектур можно банально положить болт на выравнивание...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, дело не в том, что архитектуры позволяют или не позволяют доступ к невыровненным данным. Дело в том, что стандарт языка это запрещает. И если мы нарушаем этот запрет, тогда компилятор генерирует любой код. Он может сегодня работать, а завтра - нет. Поэтому, если платформа позволяет невыровненный доступ, это никоим образом не снимает ограничений самого языка.

Comment: @MGNeo, гм... судя по всему я кое в чём заблуждался и более не могу поддерживать спор с той же убеждённостью...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный переносимый способ интерпретировать определённый тип данных из потока (буфера) байт, не опасаясь проблем доступа к невыровненным данным - это побайтово (например, с помощью `memcpy`) скопировать эти данные в место, где нужное выравнивание обеспечивается.

В случае доступа к невыровненным данным в зависимости от используемой архитектуры можно получить либо проседание производительности, либо, так называемую, ошибку шины ([Bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error)). В общем случае всё это приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Тем не менее при использовании упаковки структур (если компилятор такое поддерживает), ошибок с доступом к невыровненным данным не будет, но сам факт наличия упаковки может привести к проседанию производительности, хотя это безусловно лучше, чем UB.

В сухом остатке: если есть возможность - делайте упаковку, если нет - копируйте побайтово. Степень оверхеда от всего этого надо смотреть на конкретных примерах конкретных же архитектур.

<sup>На основании статьи [How to Access Safely Unaligned Data](https://www.alfonsobeato.net/arm/how-to-access-safely-unaligned-data/).</sup>

Comment: Иногда компилятор может "подложить собаку" с memcpy (знает он о такой функции и если размер известен при компиляции (и мал), то он вместо вызова memcpy генерит код, к сожалению не обязательно побайтовый. Был у меня такой случай на bare metal). Поэтому надежнее использовать свою (раздельно компилируемую побайтовую Memcpy (или как вы там ее назовете))

Comment: @avp это довольно странное поведение. Хотя в C и нет прямого упоминания "as-if" правила, характерного для C++, мне кажется, что компилятор не вправе производить такие "оптимизации", которые искажают наблюдаемое поведение. В частности, есть такой пункт 5.1.2.3/4 в C11: *"In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object)."*

Comment: @avp вполне может быть, что если в вашем случае не было побайтового копирования, то для той конкретной реализации это не являлось проблемой и давала вполне корректные результаты.

Comment: Да, я забыл добавить, что "встраивание memcpy" было как раз в С++ компиляторе. Не смог он предположить, что работать придется при отключенном Cache (MMU)